How to get paint and joint compound odors out of my house?
My drywall has been finished again and the smell is somehow terrible this time. Before it went away pretty quickly but now it's horrid, so any tips on how to get rid of this smell? Or will it go away on its own like before?

Do you know what type of drywall mud is being used?  It has been years since I have used any, but I do not remember it smelling when I was using it.  It is possible you are much more sensitive to it than other people, but open windows should reduced it fast.  Do not even let me see vomit, but cleaning cow pens, helping the vet cut open a cow for bad birth, septic tanks do not bother me.

By the way the type of mud used was sprayed out of a hose looking sprayer i dont know the name but it smelled awful to be honest i may have exaggerated by calling it''horrid''but it still doesnt smell good

I have never encountered sprayed on drywall, UNLESS it was texture. Texture is sprayed on the wall.  It is thinned drywall compound. If you had texture sprayed on there may have been an agent added to make it dry faster and that is making it smell.  Anyway, open the windows. all of them.
